# Подпись драйвера Windows без интернета

Tags: windows, драйвер, цифровая-подпись

подскажите. Как подписать драйвер без интернета? Я уже сгенерировал тестовую подпись. Но, чтобы подписать нужен выход в глобальную сеть, например на сервер http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll.

Мне такой вариант не подходит, мне нужно подписывать драйвера на оффлайн виртуальных машинах (под управлением Windows) они будут работать только там и нигде больше и доступ на них в глобальную сеть категорически запрещён. Так же не подходит связанная по LAN машина, которая могла бы взять на себя эти функции. Вполне себе подходит кастомизация Windows, как ДО, так и ПОСЛЕ установки, если это неизбежно.

Проблема в том, что эти драйвера динамически меняются, меняется именно INF файл, и количество вариантов можно приравнять к бесконечности. Поэтому заблаговременно сгенерить cab файлы не получится.

Что это вообще за сервер такой timestamp?
Можно ли обойти его?
Можно ли поднять свой локальный "микро timestamp сервер" ?
Отключение проверки цифровой подписи тоже не хотелось бы использовать, так как это долго (требует перезагрузки), а жизнь одной машины должна измеряться в секундах.  И чем меньше - тем лучше.
Любые идеи, обходные пути, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Подписывающий сервер тебе свой приватный ключ не отдаст, так что нельзя.

Про остальную часть вопроса не знаю.